# Duda sobre interfaces gráficas (JComboBox)

Tags: java

tengo una lista desplegable de supongamos solo dos opciones, mi pregunta es ¿de qué modo puedo yo saber cual opción ha puesto el usuario? Hay algún getter o algo por el estilo? por ejemplo, tengo estas dos opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo quiero que pasen cosas distintas dependiendo de si selecciona a Mariana o a Carlos, necesito saber cual seleccionó ¿como se hace? No sé si me di a entender. He de aclarar que me estoy metiendo en esto de las interfaces gráficas, el código de eso es solo este:

```
 String nombres[] = {"Mariana","Carlos Torres"}; 
    JComboBox listaDesplegable = new JComboBox(nombres);
    listaDesplegable.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 25);
    panel.add(listaDesplegable);
```

Actualizacion: Ahora se que puedo usar métodos como `getSelectedItem` o `getSelectedIndex` pero sinceramente no tengo del todo claro como aplicarlos, puse

```
System.out.println(listaDesplegable.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Pensando que cada vez que cambiaría de opción, me imprimiría en la consola cual tengo seleccionada, pero solo me imprime la primera. Si quiero que al seleccionar "Mariana" en la consola diga: "Has seleccionado a Mariana" y al seleccionar a Carlos me diga "Has seleccionado a Carlos" como puedo hacer?

Comment: Con getSelectedItem(), puedes ver un ejemplo aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024392/combobox-printing-out-the-selected-item

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió, pero a medias jaja, ahora si me muestra en consola a quien selecciono, pero solo la primera vez, si luego cambio a otra opción, ya no me lo muestra en consola

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta

Comment: El método `getSelectedItem` devuelve el `item` actual que hayas seleccionado. Si quieres que muestre ese mensaje, puedes hacer esto: `System.out.println("Has seleccionado a " + listaDesplegable.getSelectedItem().toString());`

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta! Pero, solo me lo muestra al ejecutar el programa, al variar entre opciones no me cambia al seleccionado actual, ¿sabes qué podría hacer?

Comment: Debes usarlo a través de un botón. Es decir, el código que te había mencionado anteriormente, lo deberías agregar al momento de hacer clic en algún botón (es un ejemplo) y ahí te saldrá el mensaje con respecto al item seleccionado.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que con el simple hecho de cambiar el valor seleccionado se produzca una acción, como imprimir el valor seleccionado, tendrás que añadir un listener con `addActionListener` e implementar la función `actionPerformed` y ahí escribes el código que quieras. Las líneas de código no está ahí y se ejecutan solas, tienes que ejecutarlas tú o que se ejecuten en respuesta a eventos con listeners.